# T-SQL appending data to NTEXT column

Tags: t-sql, ntext

Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting the error below from the SQL script?  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @Comment AS VARCHAR(2000) 
DECLARE @Len AS INT
SET @Comment = 'This is a test and only a test!'
SET @Len = LEN(@Comment)
DECLARE @ptr varbinary(16)
SELECT @ptr = TEXTPTR(Comments)
FROM [dbo].[StudentInfringement] AS SI
WHERE [SI].[InfringementId] = 2
UPDATETEXT [dbo].[StudentInfringement].[Comments] @ptr @Len NULL @Comment
```

Error message is:

> Msg 7135, Level 16, State 3, Line 9
>   Deletion length -19 is not in the
>   range of available text, ntext, or
>   image data. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL Server?? I would **strongly** recommend you change your column to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` - `NTEXT` as a data type is deprecated as of SQL Server 2005, and it's just a royal pain to work with.

`NVARCHAR(MAX)` on the other hand easily supports all the usual string manipulation functions, and would be just all the much easier to use !